# The results from the mysql query copied twicw into array

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to fetch the rows of a query into a array , but I see that the values are being copied twice ,

heres my code.

```
<?php

include("storescrpt/connect_to_sql.php");
$sql = mysql_query('select monthname(orderdate) as mon,sum(total_sales_qty) as total from salesorder where  year(orderdate)= year(now()) group by month(orderdate) ;');
$sql_count = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($sql_count>0){
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){


            $rows[] = array_values((array)$row);
                             }print json_encode($rows);print_r($rows);

}

?>
```

when i echo the array using print_r() , here what I am getting .

```
 Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => January [1] => January [2] => 29674 [3] => 29674 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => February [1] => February [2] => 22956 [3] => 22956 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => March [1] => March [2] => 35893 [3] => 35893 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => April [1] => April [2] => 64003 [3] => 64003 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => May [1] => May [2] => 43047 [3] => 43047 ) [5] => Array ( [0] => June [1] => June [2] => 44613 [3] => 44613 ) [6] => Array ( [0] => July [1] => July [2] => 72003 [3] => 72003 ) [7] => Array ( [0] => August [1] => August [2] => 116742 [3] => 116742 ) )
```

As you can see each value is copied twice which I Don't need.

Comment: Can you run your query within your database browser? Check if the result set that's returned isn't returning the duplication. If it is, you'll have to tweak your query. Or it could be the fact that you have `print json_encode($rows);` and `print_r($rows);` causing it to print twice?

Comment: nope!! actually its mysql_fetch_row() or mysql_fetch_assoc(). If we use mysql_fetch_array() it will give duplicate values.

Comment: Looking at that only then, you should complete your MYSQL_FETCH_ARRAY($sql), the syntax for `MySQL_fetch_array()` needs to have the sql statement AND the parameter that declares the way your selecting your columns i.e. `MYSQL_ASSOC`, `MYSQL_NUM` or `MYSQL_BOTH`. http://au2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php check the manual with the link. Also, please heavily consider using MYSQLImproved (`mysqli`) when coding in php